# MySQL CASE LEFT JOINS returning NULL

Tags: mysql, join, left-join, case

I have a query with a CASE statement that determines the variable `object_name` this variable is derived from either the `x_ambitions` table or the `x_trybes` table. The queries below were combined so that I could keep it simple by just executing one SQL query.

I've split the SELECT statement into two so that you have a better understanding. The two queries below. Work and pull the correct object_name from the database.

The problem I'm having when I combine the two queries is that the cases `'new_join_ambition','new_created_ambition','new_liked_ambition'` object_name returns NULL in the `LEFT JOIN`.

In the combined query, If I bring the cases: `'new_join_ambition','new_created_ambition','new_liked_ambition'` above the `'new_join_trybe','new_created_trybe','new_liked_trybe'` cases. The opposite happens. The trybe rows return `NULL`.

The two SQL queries:

A: (Retrieve Object A)

```
SELECT 
    s.id, 
    s.object_id, 
    s.type, 
    s.postee_id, 
    s.user_id,
    s.text,
    s.registered,
    CONCAT(u.x_first_name,' ',u.x_last_name) AS postee_name,
    ui.image_id AS postee_image_id,
    CASE s.type
       WHEN 'new_join_ambition' 
            OR 'new_created_ambition' 
            OR 'new_liked_ambition'         
          THEN a.name
          ELSE 'a'
    END AS object_name
FROM 
    x_share s
LEFT JOIN 
    x_user u ON u.id = s.postee_id
LEFT JOIN 
    x_user_images ui ON ui.user_id = s.postee_id
LEFT JOIN 
    x_ambitions a ON s.type IN ('new_join_ambition', 'new_created_ambition', 'new_liked_ambition') AND s.object_id = a.id
LEFT JOIN 
    x_ambition_invites ai ON s.type IN ('new_join_ambition') AND s.object_id = ai.ambition_id AND s.postee_id = ai.to
LEFT JOIN 
    x_ambition_likes al ON s.type IN ('new_liked_ambition') AND s.object_id = al.ambition_id AND s.postee_id = al.profile_id
LEFT JOIN 
    x_ambition_owner aoo ON s.type IN ('new_created_ambition') AND s.object_id = aoo.ambition_id
WHERE 
    s.user_id = '%s'
ORDER BY 
    s.registered DESC
```

B: (Retrieve Object B)

```
SELECT 
    s.id, 
    s.object_id, 
    s.type, 
    s.postee_id, 
    s.user_id,
    s.text,
    s.registered,
    CONCAT(u.x_first_name,' ',u.x_last_name) AS postee_name,
    ui.image_id AS postee_image_id,
    CASE s.type
       WHEN 'new_join_trybe'
            OR 'new_created_trybe' 
            OR 'new_liked_trybe'
          THEN t.name
          ELSE 'a'
    END AS object_name
FROM 
    x_share s
LEFT JOIN 
    x_user u ON u.id = s.postee_id
LEFT JOIN 
    x_user_images ui ON ui.user_id = s.postee_id
LEFT JOIN 
    x_trybes t ON s.type IN ('new_join_trybe', 'new_created_trybe', 'new_liked_trybe') AND s.object_id = t.id
LEFT JOIN 
    x_trybe_invites ti ON s.type IN ('new_join_trybe') AND s.object_id = ti.trybe_id AND s.postee_id = ti.to
LEFT JOIN 
    x_trybes_likes tl ON s.type IN ('new_liked_trybe') AND s.object_id = tl.trybe_id AND s.postee_id = tl.profile_id
LEFT JOIN 
    x_trybe_owner too ON s.type IN ('new_created_trybe') AND s.object_id = too.trybe_id
WHERE 
    s.user_id = '%s'
ORDER BY 
    s.registered DESC
```

I've ran both the queries and have captured images of the results of both queries.

Set A:

[image: Set A Result]

Set B:

[image: Set B Result]

How can I combine the two without the object_name returning NULL? If you have any questions please use the comments and I'll reply without hesitation.

Thanks in advance

Comment: could you make a fiddle. and post the exact intended output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know about the rest of your query, but your `case` statement is incorrect.  You have:

```
(CASE s.type
          WHEN 'new_join_ambition' OR 'new_created_ambition' OR 'new_liked_ambition'
          THEN a.name
          ELSE 'a'
END) AS object_name
```

The `OR`s end up treating the values as numbers, so this is equivalent to `WHEN 0 THEN . . .`.

What you want is this form of the `case`:

```
(CASE WHEN s.type IN ('new_join_ambition', 'new_created_ambition', 'new_liked_ambition')
      THEN a.name
      ELSE 'a'
 END) AS object_name
```

Comment: This works! Thanks for this. But one thing i've seen is the repetitive `WHEN s.type IN ('new_join_trybe','new_created_trybe','new_liked_trybe') THEN t.name`. I'm just being picky but thank you! :)